# Edit a string table resource in an exe C++

Tags: c++, string-table

I have a string table resource in my program. 
ID - IDS_TEST, 
Value - 101, 
Caption - Testing

I want to edit the value = 101 by taking the exe as input. That is, I want to change the value to 200. How is it possible? Please help me. 
I tried to do with BeginUpdateResource. But it is corrupting the .rc file itself.

Comment: Beware, the rc file is a source file that should be processed via VisualStudio, any other *source* resource editor or a plain text editor like notepad++. Only executable files should be processed with `BeginUpdateResource`

Comment: @SergeBallesta - But if i compile resource as a part of exe, it will be a part of the exe right? Is there a good example of editing the value of resource? I tried many, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: `BeginUpdateResource` is expected to change resource in another executable file not the one that uses it. You have an example in [Winapi doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-resources). But I cannot help fixing not shown code... You should show what you have tried and say what has happened.